# Application in AWS Beanstalk is is INFO state for 40 minutes from start

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I created new environment in AWS Beanstalk but it is in info state for more that 40 minutes, is it ok?[image]

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/health-enhanced-status.html#health-enhanced-status-info), the Info green occurs when

> This status is displayed when: An operation is in progress on an instance. An operation is in progress on several instances in an environment.

Thus, you have to check if you deployed something most recently? You can login to the EB instance and **inspect it from the inside** for signs of unusual long running commands.